# How can I populate a model with non-form data?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have Student, Class and StudentClass models. I would like a student to be able to join a new class by inputting the class_code into a form. To join a class the user's student_id and the class_code is saved to the StudentClass model. The student_id isn't a form field so should be obtained by querying the Student model with the logged-in user's username and returning the student_id.

models.py:

```
class StudentClass(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('class_code', 'student_id'),)
    class_code = models.ForeignKey(Class, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student_id = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

forms.py:

```
class JoinClassForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = StudentClass
        fields = ['class_code']
        exclude = ('student_id',)
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def join_class(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        joinclass_form = JoinClassForm(request.POST or None)
        if joinclass_form.is_valid():
            formclass_code = joinclass_form.data.get('class_code')
            if Class.objects.filter(class_code=formclass_code).exists():
                joinclass_form.save(commit=False)
                joinclass_form.student_id =
                Student.objects.filter(username=request.user.username).values_list('student_id', flat=True)
                joinclass_form.save()
                return redirect('assignments')
            else:
                messages.success(request, ("This class doesn't exist!"))
    else:
        joinclass_form = JoinClassForm
    return render(request, 'join_class.html', {'joinclass_form': joinclass_form})
```

I've tried using a hidden_field for student_id, excluding student_id from the form fields and saving as commit=False, and I've gotten the same error: IntegrityError Not NULL constraint failed. Is there an error in my code that I have missed or am I using the wrong method?
Thanks in advance

Edit: Forgive me but copy-paste went kinda awry on the last set of code and I have no idea how to fix it

Comment: Use StudentClass.objects.create to create the model directly

Comment: I've tried using .create() instead but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you share your both `Class` and `Student` model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help but I managed to fix it now

In case anyone needs this in the future, I realised that I made 2 mistakes:

1. I wasn't saving my form correctly in my views.py, I was trying to save the value student_id to the form rather than an object.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

2. I named my foreign key in my StudentClass table as student_id which meant that Django was renaming it as student_id_id. To fix this, I just removed _id from student_id in the StudentClass table.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to put **.username** at **request.user**. You can just say **request.user**

Comment: Doesn't request.user refer to the model instance rather than the username field? Either way, I've tried changing my code to request.user instead but I still got the same error :/